# Fastest way to copy redis data to sql server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, redis

i have a redis with more than 10M rows, i want to copy all data to sql server db, currently i wrote a nodejs script to transfer data as below

```js
redis.scan(cursor, "MATCH", "*_*", "COUNT", "100", function (err, res) {
    var keys = res[1];
    cursor = res[0];
    keys.forEach(function (id) {
        redis.hgetall(id, function (err, items) {
            let splited = Object.keys(items)[0].split("#");

            let data = {
                customerId: splited[0],
                orderId: splited[1],
            };

            sql.connect(config).then((pool) => {

                pool.request().query(
                    `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Bi]
                          ([CustomerId]
                          ,[OrderId]
                          ,[AddressId])
                    SELECT
                          ${data.customerId}
                          ,${data.orderId}
                          ,[dbo].[Address].Id
                    FROM [dbo].[Address] where CustomerId = ${data.customerId}`
                )
            })
        })
    })
})
```

but it takes 1 day to complete, so how should i optimize the script or is there any alternative way to transfer data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk inserting with Node mssql package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663017/bulk-inserting-with-node-mssql-package)

Comment: Is it a one time or do you want to sync it on a regular base to MySQL?

Comment: @GuyKorland i want to run it regulary, probably every 3 days

Comment: @Charlieface tnx but no, because i get "Address.Id" in the query from another table

Comment: But you could load up a temp table, put an index on it and join on that. `10M data` means 10 megabyte? 10 million rows? What are your indexes?

Comment: @Charlieface 10M rows, i dont get what do you mean by index, but i want to join with address table on customerId

Comment: @Charlieface cool but if i create a temp table like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-options-callback), how can i join to AddressTable in the bulk

Comment: Create a local temp table (single `#`), bulk insert into it, add a good index (looks like `CustomerId, OrderId` would work well), then execute a [standard joined insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469503/sql-insert-into-with-inner-join). Your temp table will be dropped when the connection is closed

Comment: @Charlieface i got your point, that should work, i will try it, tnxx

Answer (score 2):

The Redis Module [RedisGears](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/) has a recipe called rgsync[enter link description here](https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync) using this module you can make sure each update to Redis is being synchronized back to your SQLServer.

See an example here: https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync/tree/master/examples/mssql